# Publish article by date by scheduling a PHP/MySQL INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing system to submit articles using PHP into a MySQL database. I would like to implement some sort of queue, so I was wondering if I could allow the submitter to select a date/time and then the Insert would perform at that time. Is this possible?

Comment: Does the insert need to be scheduled, or can you insert immediately and filter records `WHERE publish_at < NOW()`?

Comment: Makes a lot more sense to have a `PublishDate` or `PublishTime` column in the `articles` table.

Comment: Why not have a column that is the published date and set it to the date you want the content to go live?

Comment: I guess it would make more sense to have the query select rows only with submission time before or at NOW(). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way to accomplish this is not to time the insert, but to time the publishing of the article. Instead of inserting at a specified time:

- If the author selects a time that is in the future, add the time to publish_time column
- When displaying the article only display the ones in which publish_time is in the past.

Comment: Just one thing, the `publish_time` field defaults to `NOW()` if not given.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a [MySQL Event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) or, probably better solution, setup a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), if you're on Linux.

Alternatevely, you could try with [phpJobScheduler](http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/).

Answer (score 1):

You can create additional table in DB ex: article_to_publish with publish_date column and then run some publish action by cron.

If you need more fun you can look at http://celeryproject.org/

Comment: You need a whole table for this?

Comment: Jared Farrish - do you have other idea how to persist data?

Comment: Yes, of course. Add a date/time field to the articles and use that find "published" articles. See my comment under the question.

Comment: True, but rar asked about schedule insert operation ;) Not remodeling existing solution

Comment: @rar asked for the *wrong* approach. Did I downvote? No, but what you describe is IMO overkill for the *intent* of what the OP is after.